# Bootstrap scrollspy does not work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I have added Bootstrap scroll-spy to my page, following the bootstrap manual, but it's not working and not really sure what I'm doing wrong

my code looks like this:

Body:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="150">
```

Nav:

```
<nav  class="navbar  navbar-default navbar-toggleable bg-faded navbar-light fixed-top" id="navbar" > 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="../media/logo.png" class=" align-top" alt=""> 
        </a>

     <div class="nav-links collapse navbar-collapse col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" id="collapseNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav" >
            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a  class="" id="title_boutTheCompany" href="#link-aboutTheCompany">Company</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a  class="" href="#link-staff" id="title_Team">Team</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="" href="#link-contacts" id="title_Contact">Contacts</a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="border: none;">
                    <a  class="" href="#link-freeTime" id="title_freeTime">Free time</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
      </div> 
      <div class="navBtn d-sm-none">
            <button class=" navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNav" aria-controls="collapseNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" id="toogleIcon">
                   <span class="fa fa-angle-down my-toggler" id="faToggler"></span>
            </button>
       </div>
</nav>
```

The divs that should activate the spy:

```
<div class="anchor" id="link-aboutTheCompany"></div>
<div class="anchor" id="link-staff"></div>
<div class="anchor" id="link-freeTime"></div>
<div class="anchor" id="link-contacts"></div>
```

And in my scss i have:

```
li{
     &:active > a {
       display:block;
       color: red;
       text-decoration: underline;
     }
}
```

An in my js:

```
$('#navbar').scrollspy();
```

Comment: It could be helpful to add this in a JSfiddle. However i have noticed that the js is initialising on an ID that doesn't exist aswell as the data-target grabbing a presumed class that isn't in the code either.

Comment: @DavidPicksley the ID and the class are defined in the nav tag, I accidentally didn't copy that part in. Just edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

you have to give a height for your content which your scrollspy spy to

for example:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="150" style="height:1000px;overflow-y:auto;">
```

A better way：
add a scroll event listener to your DOM

every time you scrolled , it will refresh the scrollspy

here is the javascript:

(if your html has a lot of imgs)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
      var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
    });
});
```

(if your html has a little imgs)

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
      var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
    });
```