# ng-bootstrap scrollspy doesn't work without height?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am using ng-bootstrap `[ngbScrollSpy]` directive in my project, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/scrollspy/api), but it didn't work - on scroll the active item doesn't change.

My code is the following:

```html
<div>
    <div class="sticky-top">
        <ul class="nav menu-sidebar">
            <li >
                <a [ngbScrollSpyItem]="[spy, 'about']">About</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a [ngbScrollSpyItem]="spy" fragment="schedule">Schedule</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a [ngbScrollSpyItem]="spy" fragment="hotel">Information about the hotel</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div ngbScrollSpy #spy="ngbScrollSpy" >
        <section ngbScrollSpyFragment="about">
            <h3>About</h3>
            <p>{{some long long text and content}}</p>
        </section>
        <section ngbScrollSpyFragment="schedule">
            <h3>Schedule</h3>
            <p>{{some long long text and content}}</p>
        </section>
        <section ngbScrollSpyFragment="hotel">
            <h3>Information about the hotel</h3>
            <p>{{some long long text and content}}</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I saw [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504192/bootstrap-scrollspy-does-not-work) that my problem is that I didn't provide `height` to my div, and that's true.

but my scroll spy sections spread through the whole page, not a small div, (the nav itself is `sticky-top`). so I cannot give it height.

I understood that there is alternative way - to refresh the scrollspy on window scroll, but I don't find correct code that may help me.

can you solve my problem?
provide me code for refreshing the scrollspy / give me tips about the height / help me to find another corresponding element.

thanks a lot!

attaching link to [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-i9t6ju?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmy-scrollspy%2Fmy-scrollspy.component.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fmy-scrollspy%2Fmy-scrollspy.component.ts,src%2Fmy-scrollspy%2Fmy-scrollspy.component.css,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Hi, can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui, I added stackblitz link. see the my-scrollspy component, If you add height to the ngbScrollSpy it will work

Comment: You can adjust your layout in a way to make `.content` block scrollable https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1r9su9

Comment: @yurzui- I have a footer to this page (I added it now in the stackblitz demo) which is in the main component, and I don't want two scrollbars in this page.

Comment: Can you please send me that updated stackblitz?

Comment: Here you'll see it https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-m1havs?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seemed to be no solution for my demands, I decided to create my own scrollspy element via two directives:

1. `scrollTo` directive will be responsible for scrolling to the section on pressing the `li` link

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollTo]'
})
export class ScrollToDirective {

  @Input() target = '';
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    const targetElement = document.querySelector(this.target);
    if(targetElement)
      targetElement.scrollIntoView({block: 'start',behavior: 'smooth', inline:'nearest'});
  }
}
```

2. `scrolledTo` directive will be responsible for detecting when scrolling to current element

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrolledTo]',
  exportAs: 'scrolledTo'
})
export class ScrolledToDirective {
  @Input() isLast:boolean = false;
  focus = false;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll() {
    const elementPosition = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    const elementHeight = this.el.nativeElement.clientHeight;

    //you can change the check according to your requirements
    const scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset - window.screen.height / 2 ;
    this.focus = scrollPosition >= elementPosition && scrollPosition <= elementPosition + elementHeight;
    if(this.isLast)
      this.focus = scrollPosition >= elementPosition;

  }
}
```

and the html will be the following

```html
<div>
    <div class="sticky-top">
        <ul class="nav menu-sidebar">
            <li >
                <a scrollTo target="#about" [class.active]="scrolledToElement1.focus">About</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a scrollTo target="#schedule" [class.active]="scrolledToElement2.focus">Schedule</a>
            </li>
            <li >
                <a scrollTo target="#hotel" [class.active]="scrolledToElement3.focus">Information about the hotel</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div >
        <section scrolledTo #scrolledToElement1="scrolledTo" id="about">
            <h3>About</h3>
            <p>{{some long long text and content}}</p>
        </section>
        <section scrolledTo #scrolledToElement2="scrolledTo" id="schedule">
            <h3>Schedule</h3>
            <p>{{some long long text and content}}</p>
        </section>
        <section scrolledTo #scrolledToElement3="scrolledTo" id="hotel">
            <h3>Information about the hotel</h3>
            <p>{{some long long text and content}}</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

credits:

- [scrollTo directive](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web-development/9781838989439/2/ch02lvl1sec14/creating-a-basic-directive-that-allows-you-to-vertically-scroll-to-an-element)
- [scrolledTo directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55777845/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-has-scrolled-down-or-crossed-to-a-particular-eleme)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I use the NgbScrollSpy from [@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/scrollspy/api) (I imagine it's very similar library)

What I do:

I wrapper all (include the navigation) in the

```
<div class="wrapper" ngbScrollSpy #spy="ngbScrollSpy" 
   rootMargin="2px"  [threshold]="1.0" >

  <div class="sticky-top pt-4 pb-4 bg-white">
   ..here the navigation...
  </div>
      ..here the sections...
  <section ngbScrollSpyFragment="about">
  </section>
      //the last I use margin-bottom:2rem;
  <section ngbScrollSpyFragment="hotel" style="margin-bottom:10rem"
  </section>
</div>
```

See the "threshold". This indicate what percent (1 is 100% ) should be visible to "change" the active fragment

The wrapper class

```
.wrapper{
   height:100%;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
}
```

I force the class of the link using

```
//remove all the class for the link
a{
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:8px 16px;
}
a.custom-active{
  color:white;
  background-color:royalblue
}
```

And each link I use

```
<a  [class.custom-active]="spy.active=='about'">About</a>
```

Well, the problem is how "scroll to". The "links" should work as link.

The first is indicate to the "router" that should take account the "fragments"

If our component is an standalone component we need use a provider, the provideRouter

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([], withInMemoryScrolling({anchorScrolling:'enabled'})),
  ]
})
```

Then, we need take account that really our page has **no** scroll,  **the div "wrapper"** is who has the scroll. So we subscribe to router.events and when the event has an "anchor" we scroll the "wrapper" div

```
  constructor(router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(filter((e:any) => e.anchor)).subscribe((e: any) => {

      (document.getElementById('wrapper') as any).scrollTop+=
                 (document.getElementById(e.anchor)?.getBoundingClientRect().top||0)
                                                       -72; //<--this is the offset
    });
  }
```

In this [stactblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9p74yv?file=src%2Fmain.ts) you have a working example

**Update**: Listening the changes of ngbScrollSpy.

If we want to see a footer, we can use activeChange event of the [ngbScrollSpy](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/scrollspy/api)

Imagine we define an output in our `myscrollspy`

```
@Output()scrollEmit=new EventEmitter<any>()
```

We can, in the event activeChange emit the "fragment"

```
<div ngbScrollSpy #spy="ngbScrollSpy" class="content"   
                  rootMargin="2px"  [threshold]="1.0"
                  (activeChange)="scrollEmit.next($event)"
>
```

Now, we can "listen" this event in our app-root.component to change a variable `displayFooter:boolean=false`

```
   <app-my-scrollspy (scrollEmit)="displayFooter=$event=='hotel'">
   </app-my-scrollspy>

   @if(displayFooter)
   {
      <div  style="position:absolute;bottom:0;z-index:1000">
        <h3>footer to be displayed when finish scrolling the document</h3>
      </div>
   }
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fcibvo?file=src%2Fmy-scrollspy%2Fmy-scrollspy.component.html,src%2Fmy-scrollspy%2Fmy-scrollspy.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fmy-scrollspy%2Fmy-scrollspy.component.css,src%2Findex.html)

Comment: I cannot have scrolling to the content div, because I have a footer to the page (in the main component) and if I will do scrolling - I will always see the footer. I would like to see it after the last section, like regular page https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-m1havs?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: @Ayala, for this, you can use the event `activeChange`, I update my answer and add a forked stackblitz based in your code.